# How to merge a multidimensional list into one list of tuples?

Tags: python, numpy, arraylist

Suppose we have the following multi-dimensional list :

```
import numpy as np
lst = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Expected output :

```
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

My problem is that the list 'lst' varies in size, otherwise I would achieve the wanted result with one for loop. I tried generalizing the task, here goes my attempt :

```
lst = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
test = np.array(list(zip(lst[i] for i in range(len(lst)))))
```

Clearly, this isn't the result I wanted. Is there a straight forward way of doing so without iterating over each element in the list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `*` to "unpack" `lst`:

```py
lst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
test = list(map(list, zip(*lst)))
print(test)
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 4, 7], 
 [2, 5, 8], 
 [3, 6, 9]]
```

Comment: You, sir, have the fastest compile time & you stayed true to my original code. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy.transpose` instead

```
import numpy as np
result = np.transpose(np.array(lst))
```

or simply `np.array(lst).T`

Comment: I was too blinded to see that my wanted output is simply the transpose of my matrix ... Thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

Using Numpy swapaxes

```
arr = np.array(lst)
arr=np.swapaxes(arr,1,0)
```

Comment: Simple & efficient. I timed the three answers & validated the fastest response. Thank you though